# Is my proof that $(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{C}, \oplus, \odot)$ is a vector space correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V = \mathcal{P}$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{C}$, and operations $\oplus: (p \oplus q)(t) = p(t) + q(t)$, $\odot: (\alpha \odot p)(t) = \alpha\cdot p(t)$, $p, q \in \mathcal{P}, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove with **argumentation**, that $(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{C}, \oplus, \odot)$ creates a vector space.

---

For purposes of this proof, let $p(x) = \alpha_0 + \cdots + \alpha_n x^n$, $q(x) = \beta_0 + \cdots + \beta_n x^n$, $s(x) = \gamma_0 + \cdots + \gamma_n x^n$, $p, q, s \in \mathcal{P}, \alpha,\beta,\gamma, x\in\mathbb{C}$.

1. $(\forall \vec{a},\vec{b} \in V)(\vec{a} \oplus \vec{b} = \vec{b} \oplus \vec{a})$

Because addition of polynomials happens at some constant point $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and also from fact that complex numbers are commutative, it is true that $\alpha_0 + \cdots + \alpha_n x^n + \beta_0 + \cdots + \beta_n x^n = \beta_0 + \cdots + \beta_n x^n + \alpha_0 + \cdots + \alpha_n x^n$.

2. $(\forall \vec{a},\vec{b}, \vec{c} \in V)(\vec{a} \oplus (\vec{b}\oplus \vec{c}) = (\vec{a} \oplus \vec{b}) \oplus \vec{c})$

This axiom is also true due to point-to-point addition of polynomials. At certain point $x\in\mathbb{C}$ polynomials are some constant number. From associativity of complex numbers, it follows that this axioms is also true.

3. $(\exists \vec{b}\in V)(\forall \vec{a} \in V)(\vec{a} \oplus \vec{b} = \vec{a})$

To find this polynomial, let $\lambda = 0, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then  $\lambda\cdot p(x) = 0\cdot\alpha_0 + \cdots 0\cdot\alpha_n x^n := \mathcal{O}(x)$ is a zero polynomial, which follows this property for all polynomials.

4. $(\forall \vec{a} \in V)(\exists \vec{b}\in V)(\vec{a} \oplus \vec{b}  = \vec{0})$

Let $\lambda = -1, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\lambda\cdotp(x) = -\alpha_0 - \cdots - \alpha_n x^n := -p(x)$ is an opposite polynomial which satisfies $p(x) - p(x) = \mathcal{O}(x)$.

5. $(\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathcal{F})(\forall \vec{a} \in V)((\alpha \cdot \beta)\odot \vec{a} = \alpha \odot (\beta \odot \vec{a}))$

It is certain that $(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot s(x) = (\alpha\cdot\beta)\gamma_0 + \cdots + (\alpha\cdot\beta)\gamma_n x^n = \alpha(\beta\cdot p(x)) = \alpha(\beta\gamma_0) + \cdots \alpha(\beta\gamma_n x^n).$

6. $(\forall \vec{a} \in V)(1\odot\vec{a} = \vec{a})$.

It is easily shown, because $1\cdot p(x) = 1\alpha_0 + \cdots + 1\alpha_n x^n = \alpha_0 + \cdots + \alpha_n x^n$.

7. $(\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathcal{F})(\forall \vec{a} \in V)((\alpha + \beta)\odot \vec{a} = \alpha\odot\vec{a} \oplus \beta\odot\vec{a})$

Again, by algebraic manipulation and from properties of complex numbers it follows that $(\alpha + \beta)\cdot s(x) = (\alpha + \beta)\gamma_0 + \cdots + (\alpha + \beta)\gamma_n x^n = \alpha\cdot s(x) + \beta\cdot s(x) = \alpha\gamma_0 + \cdots + \alpha\gamma_n x^n + \beta\gamma_0 + \cdots + \beta\gamma_n x^n.$

8. $(\forall \alpha \in \mathcal{F})(\forall \vec{a}, \vec{b} \in V)(\alpha \odot (\vec{a} \oplus \vec{b}) = (\alpha \odot \vec{a}) \oplus (\alpha \odot \vec{b})$

Using algebraic manipulation it can easily be shown that $\alpha\cdot(q(x) + s(x)) = \alpha(\beta_0 + \cdots + \beta_n x^n + \gamma_0 + \cdots + \cdots +\gamma_n x^n) = (\alpha\cdot q(x)) + (\alpha \cdot s(x)) = (\alpha\beta_0 + \alpha\beta_n x^n) + (\alpha\gamma_0 + \cdots + \alpha\gamma_n x^n).$

Because $(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{C}, \oplus, \odot)$ follows all axioms of vector space, it is a vector space.

---

Is my proof correctly written?